# Swift: protocols: Capturing compatibility between types

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am hoping to write code that allows me to build bindings between different types like this:

```
Map.add(1.0).to(CGPointZero) // (x:1.0, y:1.0)
```

This is a contrived example, but if it can work, can be a nice way of capturing relations.  In C++, this would be straight forward, you would create something like this:

```
class Binding<typename FromType> {

    FromType from;

    to<typename ToType>(ToType toType) {
        return from + toType
    }
}

class Map {

     Binding<T> add<T>(t:T) {
        return Binding<T>(t:t)
    }
}
```

and the compiler would figure out whether or not these types could be added.

Swift is another animal though, and you need to capture this relationship ahead of type with a protocol.  It might look something like this:

```
public protocol ScalarArithmetic {
    typealias SomeScalarType

     func +(lhs: SomeScalarType, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

//  Double + CGPoint
public func + (lhs:Double, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}

//  Float + CGPoint
public func + (lhs:Float, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}


class Binding<T> {
    var from: T

    init(t:T) { self.from = t }

    func to<S:ScalarArithmetic where S.SomeScalarType == T>(s:S) -> S {
        return self.from + s
    }
}

class Map {

    class func add<T>(t:T) -> Binding<T> {
        return Binding<T>(t:t)
    }
}
```

The question though, is how do you bind a type - let's use CGPoint for an example, with multiple scalar types, so the above machinery could be used for a range of bindings (like the C++ sample above).

This doesn't work, as the compiler doesn't like duplicate statements:

```
extension CGPoint : ScalarArithmetic {
    typealias SomeScalarType = Double

}

extension CGPoint : ScalarArithmetic {
    typealias SomeScalarType = Float
}
```

I tried capturing the scalar type as in it's own protocol - and maybe that's the way to do it, but it pushes the problem down the road a bit:

```
public protocol SomeScalarType {}
extension Double: SomeScalarType {}
extension Float: SomeScalarType {}

public protocol ScalarArithmetic {
    func +(lhs: SomeScalarType, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

//  Double + CGPoint
public func + (lhs:Double, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}

//  Float + CGPoint
public func + (lhs:Float, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}

extension CGPoint: ScalarArithmetic {} // does not conform to ScalarArithmetic
// since it is not implemented in terms of the ScalarArithmetic protocol,
// despite having the necessary operators.
```

So to talk myself into my own answer, does that leave as the only option, making ScalarType "convertable-enough", that it can be cast to the desired primitive type:

```
public func + (lhs:SomeScalarType, rhs:SomeScalarType) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}
```

How would I do this, and/or are there better solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Swift intentionally does not coerce types for you very much. That's a language choice, and circumventing it is going to be hard. You cannot `+` arbitrary numeric types. Your C++ example works because arbitrary number things can add, whereas they can't in Swift.

IMO, the correct answer for what you're trying to do is exactly:

```
public func + (lhs:Double, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + CGFloat(lhs), y:rhs.y + CGFloat(lhs))
}
```

Full stop. But this is a terrible thing to attach to `+`. You cannot `+` a scalar and a vector meaningfully. This kind of thing is better defined as:

```
public func + (lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: rhs.x + lhs.x, y:rhs.y + lhs.y)
}
```

And then craft the `CGPoint` you want to add (even if you have to create a `Diagonal(1)` function to help. I know this is a contrived example, but I expect the same is true for the full problem. Making types automatically coerce should be done with extreme care. It is almost always better to create an `init` that lets you explicitly convert one to the other. Then operators makes sense.

This is all a strength in Swift in allowing much stronger type safety. For instance, I have some code like this:

```
// Frequency and Time are reciprocols
public func *(lhs: SignalTime,      rhs: SignalFrequency) -> Double { return lhs.seconds * rhs.hertz }
public func *(lhs: SignalFrequency, rhs: SignalTime)      -> Double { return rhs * lhs }

public func /(lhs: Double, rhs: SignalFrequency) -> SignalTime { return SignalTime(seconds: lhs / rhs.hertz) }
public func /(lhs: Double, rhs: SignalTime)      -> SignalFrequency { return SignalFrequency(hertz: lhs / rhs.seconds) }

// Frequency can be scaled by a constant
public func *(lhs: SignalFrequency, rhs: Double)          -> SignalFrequency { return SignalFrequency(hertz: lhs.hertz * rhs) }
public func *(lhs: Double,          rhs: SignalFrequency) -> SignalFrequency { return rhs * lhs }
```

It's all very explicit and even tedious, but it should be. There are useful ways to combine these types and there are illegal ways to combine these types. `x/y` returns a completely different type than `y/x`. Doing it this way has caught several "oh, I was accidentally multiplying a frequency by a frequency" bugs at the compile stage. Trying to make all of this "magically work" with minimal code tends to over-extend the types in ways that permit illegal operations.

I'd avoid `ScalarArithmetic` until you had a really good and unambiguous use case. If you have a different example, it'd be interesting to look at, but I expect the answer is similar. Be careful of over-extending coercion.

Comment: Thanks, I keep coming back to the truism that if it seems to hard, I'm doing it the wrong way.  For what it's worth though, I was trying to ape the d3.js style of let f = scale.from(0, 1).to(0, screenWidth).mappingFunction; let finalX = f(0.5), in such a way to catch incompatible types by restricting valid options in to(), to reflect compatibility with the type in from() - if that makes any sense.

Comment: That syntax seems very ambiguous. If you give `from`, but fail to give `to`, what happens? Is it a partial application? (Swift has better ways to achieve that.) I'm having trouble figuring out what `finalX` is in this case, but I would think you mean something like `func scale<T,U>(#from: T, #to: T) -> (U -> U)`. Then `f: Float -> Float = scale(from: (0,1), to:(0, screenWidth))`. That would enforce from and to having the same types at least (though again, I'm not quite clear what you example is supposed to do, mapping scalar to what I guess is an affine transform).

Comment: At least given your example, I'm not sure this is a syntax that plays to good Swift coding practices. It may be more tied to the strengths and limitations of JS. (Which is why you must be very careful when porting syntax from one language to another. It seldom is a very good idea unless you've proven that the two languages have similar characteristics over the space that the syntax covers. That will seldom be the case for Swift and JS.)

Comment: It's just a general pattern - method chaining (JUnit is / was a good example), where you can build up a construct such a way that each choice determines what can come next.  To answer your first question, if you only had from(), you could / would only get an option for to(), and could not get the mapping function directly.  Also, I did ask this question on the devforums and the answer from Apple was effectively that it was a limitation of the use of the protocols aka trait approach for generics.  C++ is less constrained, as noted by all parties.

Comment: Absolutely agreed on Swift vs C++. The choice of how to manage generics was definitely a language choice, not an accident. (Some things should definitely become more flexible in the future, but by design it will not become C++). My point, though, was, what if the expression stopped at `from()`. What is the type of the returned value? If it's not meaningful (and concrete) type at each step, it probably won't fit well into Swift's type system, and is probably fighting Swift (and most strongly-typed languages w/o first-class types).

Comment: For a skeletal example to answer your question (non shipping, no-op code) : <playground>class Map { class func from(min:Double, max:Double) -> To { return To() }}
class To { func to(min:Double, max:Double) -> Mapping { return Mapping() }}
class Mapping { func mapping() -> (Double) -> Double { return { d in
 println("\(d)"); return d }}}
let translate = Map.from(0.0, max: 1.0).to(0.0, max: 100.0).mapping()
translate(1.0)
</playground>
I don't always go this far in constraining choices, but like the general pattern for safety and readability.